# number theory to verifying prime power numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime, $s$ is a prime and $t$ is an integer such that $p|t$. Suppose that $\gcd(p, s^t-1)= 1.$ And suppose that $t$ has at least one prime divisor which is not $s$ and also is not contained in the set of prime divisors of product of terms $s^{ti}-1$ with $i$ varying from $2$ to $p$.

Now I wanted to know whether it's possible for the fraction $$\frac{s^{pt}-1}{s^t-1}$$ to be a prime power?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).